# Modify the path to files when launching the script / Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I have several spiders that I launch from a core.py script, like this :

```
# ----- This part launch all given spiders ----- #

process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())

process.crawl(CarrefourSpider)
process.crawl(ParapharmaSpider)
process.crawl(EbaySpider)

process.start() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```

However each spider references to a file : it wasnt working without giving the absolute path so it looks like this for now :

```
class CarrefourSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "carrefour_bot"

def start_requests(self):
    base_url="https://new.carrefour.fr/s?q="
    test_file = open(r"C:\Users\User\scrapybot\scrapybot\spiders\files\to_collect_carrefour.csv", "r")
    reader = csv.reader(test_file)
    for row in reader:
        if row:
            url = row[0]
            absolute_url = base_url+url
            print(absolute_url)
            yield scrapy.Request(absolute_url, meta={'dont_redirect': True, "handle_httpstatus_list": [302, 301, 502]}, callback=self.parse)
```

The thing is that I won't be the only one person using this script. I would like to know if there is a way to specify the path before launching the core.py script,  instead of modifying the path into each script. Or just ideas to make it more flexible :]

Please let me know if I am not clear ! Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from os import path

script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, './output03.txt')
print(file_path)
fptr = open(file_path, 'w')
```

This way the directory will be selected where script reside

Answer (score 0):

A more elegant way would be to leverage scrapy settings:

```
class CarrefourSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "carrefour_bot"

def start_requests(self):
    base_url="https://new.carrefour.fr/s?q="
    test_file = open(self.settings["URL_FILE_LOCATION"], "r")
    reader = csv.reader(test_file)
    for row in reader:
        if row:
            url = row[0]
            absolute_url = base_url+url
            print(absolute_url)
            yield scrapy.Request(absolute_url, meta={'dont_redirect': True, "handle_httpstatus_list": [302, 301, 502]}, callback=self.parse)
```

Now each user can customize the value of `URL_FILE_LOCATION` in their local settings.